# site_url with path and custom variable

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm not very familiar with PHP and have been trying my hardest to figure out how to create this URL. So far, this is working:

```
<?php echo site_url($p->post_title) ?>
```

Where post title is defined by the [Mapify.it](http://mapify.it/) Wordpress plugin. The result is:

```
http://siteurl.com/post_title
```

What I'd like to do is add a string before it, ideally `?s=` or `/search/`, but when I try to add this before `$p->post_title` I'm still generating the above URL. Variations such as:

```
<?php echo site_url('?s=', $p->post_title) ?>
<?php echo site_url('/search/', $p->post_title) ?>
```

produce `http://siteurl.com/?s=` and ignore the variable. Nothing seems to do what I want.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you need the following url format,

```
http://siteurl.com/?s=Here come the post title
```

So,

```
<?php echo site_url("?s=".$p->post_title) ?>
```

OR

```
<?php echo site_url("/search/".$p->post_title) ?>
```

should work.

Comment: I found a different solution but I'm sure this is cleaner and can confirm it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

```
<?php echo site_url('?s='), $p->post_title ?>
```

Comment: Changed "," into "." since it is not a valid php code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding custom URL Parameters directly, I'd suggest you to use WordPress built-in function `add_query_arg()`, it's more cleaner.

Here is an usage example:

```
$url = get_site_url();
$params = array(
 's' => $p->post_title
);
echo add_query_arg($params, $url);
```

You can specify multiple parameters this way.
For ref: Check [add_query_arg()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg)